# File couldn´t be opened. ENSCOCOAERRORDOMAIN256

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I try to read a csv file to get the Data (and safe later to json) but the only Thing i get is:

`The file “bsp_20211203.csv” couldn’t be opened. ENSCOCOAERRORDOMAIN256`

The 'uri' is a String which i get from the DocumentPicker plugin.
This looks like `file:///Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/device/data/Containers/Data/Application/appl/tmp/org.reactjs.native.example.AwesomeProject-Inbox/bsp_20211203.csv`

So this would be my Code.

```
RNFS.readDir(uri)
      .then((result) => {
        // stat the first file
        return Promise.all([RNFS.stat(result[0].path), result[0].path]);
      })
      .then((statResult) => {
        if (statResult[0].isFile()) {
          // if we have a file, read it
          var content = RNFS.readFile(uri);
          console.log('--------------------------')
          console.log(content);
          return RNFS.readFile(statResult[1], 'utf8');
        }
    
        return 'no file';
      })
      .then((contents) => {
        // log the file contents
        console.log(contents);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.message, err.code);
      });
  }
```

its running on an ios Simulator which is runnning by React-Native-CLI.
Any recomandings?